# C - Printing word/freq BST in order of freq instead of word

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've created a program that collects words and their frequencies from a text file. At the moment I've managed to save the words and their frequencies in a binary search tree. The problem is that the program prints out the words and their frequencies in alphabetic (key) order. I need to print out the top-100 words according to their frequency. I would like to use the binary search tree, even if it isn't the most effective way of doing this task.

If I understand correctly, the maximum heap structure could be used here, but I need more specific steps to go on by. I am very new to data structures.

My structures look like this:

```
typedef char data_type[MAXLEN];

typedef struct bstnd {
    data_type data;
    int freq;
    struct bstnd* parent;
    struct bstnd* left;
    struct bstnd* right;
} bstnode, *pbstnode;

typedef struct bt {
    pbstnode root;
} bst;
```

My main function looks like this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){

bst tree;
tree.root=0;

FILE * fp;
int i=0, c=0;
char buffer[MAXLEN];
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (fp==0) {
    printf("Usage: %s [file]\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
while (!feof(fp)) {
    c = fgetc(fp);

    if (isalpha(c) || c == '\'' || c == '’' || c == '‘') {
        buffer[i]=tolower(c);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        buffer[i]='\0';
        if (isalpha(buffer[0])) {
               bst_insert( &tree, buffer );
            }
            buffer[0]='\0';
            i=0;
        }
    }

    print_tree_inorder(tree);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you know how many items there are in your tree, you can allocate memory for an array of its nodes, copy them into the array, than `qsort` them on frequency (or alpha if the same). Whether or not the nodes contain the actual words, or pointers to them, should not matter. Or even just make an array of pointers to your nodes and sort the pointers.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the correct number of nodes by returning 1 everytime a new node was created by int bst_insert() and counting them up in a variable. So how would I go about copying the nodes in to an array?

Comment: Pass 1. Traverse the tree and count the nodes. Allocate memory for an array of node pointers. Pass 2. Traverse the tree and write the node pointers into the array. Write a `cmp()` function for `qsort`. Call `qsort` to sort the pointers. Step 3. Print the first 100 nodes pointed to by the sorted pointer array.